# How do I access array of hash in perl?

Tags: arrays, perl, hash, push

I have a big array of hashes, I want to grab some hash from the array and insert into new array without changing the first array. I am having problem pushing the hash to array, how do I access the ith element which is a hash.

```
my @myarray;
$my_hash->{firstname} = "firstname";
$my_hash->{lastname} = "lastname";
$my_hash->{age} = "25";
$my_hash->{location} = "WI";
push @myarray,$my_hash;

$my_hash->{firstname} = "Lily";
$my_hash->{lastname} = "Bily";
$my_hash->{age} = "22";
$my_hash->{location} = "CA";
push @myarray,$my_hash;

$my_hash->{firstname} = "something";
$my_hash->{lastname} = "otherthing";
$my_hash->{age} = "22";
$my_hash->{location} = "NY";
push @myarray,$my_hash;

my @modifymyhash;
for (my $i=0;$i<2; $i++)  {
        print "No ".$i."\n";
        push (@modifymyhash, $myarray[$i]);
        print "".$myarray[$i]."\n";  #How do I print first ith element of array which is hash.
 }
```

Answer (score 14):

First you should

```
use strict;
use warnings;
```

then define

```
my $my_hash;
```

initialize `$my_hash` before you assign values, because otherwise you overwrite it and all three elements point to the same hash

```
$my_hash = {};
```

and finally, to access the hash's members

```
$myarray[$i]->{firstname}
```

or to print the whole hash, you can use [Data::Dumper](http://perldoc.perl.org/Data/Dumper.html) for example

```
print Dumper($myarray[$i])."\n";
```

or some other method, [How can I print the contents of a hash in Perl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1162245/how-can-i-print-the-contents-of-a-hash-in-perl) or [How do I print a hash structure in Perl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2431032/how-do-i-print-a-hash-structure-in-perl)

**Update** to your comment:

You copy the hashes with

```
push (@modifymyhash, $myarray[$i]);
```

into the new array, which works perfectly. You can verify with

```
foreach my $h (@myarray) {
    print Dumper($h), "\n";
}

foreach my $h (@modifymyhash) {
    print Dumper($h), "\n";
}
```

that both arrays have the same hashes.

If you want to make a deep copy, instead of just the references, you can allocate a new hash and copy the `ith` element into the copy. Then store the copy in `@modifymyhash`

```
my $copy = {};
%{$copy} = %{$myarray[$i]};
push (@modifymyhash, $copy);
```

Comment: I have used both string and warnings. And I have initialize and define my_hash as well. I want to push the whole hash into new array. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @mysteriousboy You have already pushed the hashes into `@modifymyhash`. What's wrong with that?

Answer (score 2):

To dereference a hash, use `%{ ... }`:

```
print  %{ $myarray[$i] }, "\n";
```

This probably still does not do what you want. To print a hash nicely, you have to iterate over it, there is no "nice" stringification:

```
print $_, ':', $myarray[$i]{$_}, "\n" for keys %{ $myarray[$i] };
```