# Reading a file content into perl hash using map

Tags: perl

I am trying to read the contents of a file into a hash
file contents look line,

```
A|A1
B|B1
C|C1
```

the code I have is

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;

my $instAttribFileName="DATABYIDENTIFIER_InstCommonAttrList.config";

open(IFH,$instAttribFileName) or die "cannot open file";
my %attribhash = ();
%attribhash = map {chomp; split /\|/} (<IFH>);
print Dumper %attribhash;
```

Dumper does not print the hash but reads A,A1 etc into seperate variables.

what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: it works here. Try adding a backslash in front of the hash: `print Dumper \%attribhash`

Comment: https://metacpan.org/pod/DDP works better than Data::Dumper

Answer (score 7):

According to [perldoc perldata](https://perldoc.perl.org/perldata.html#List-value-constructors):

> LISTs do automatic interpolation of sublists. That is, when a LIST is
>   evaluated, each element of the list is evaluated in list context, and
>   the resulting list value is interpolated into LIST just as if each
>   individual element were a member of LIST. Thus arrays and hashes lose
>   their identity in a LIST

So you need to pass the hash by reference to [`Dumper()`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Data::Dumper#Functions) or else it will be flattened into a list of separate arguments. For example, if you have:

```
my %foo = ( a => 'A', b => 'B');
print Dumper %foo;
```

**Output**:

```
$VAR1 = 'b';
$VAR2 = 'B';
$VAR3 = 'a';
$VAR4 = 'A';
```

but if you pass a reference to  `%foo` instead (by putting a backslash in front):

```
print Dumper \%foo;
```

we get:

```
$VAR1 = {
          'b' => 'B',
          'a' => 'A'
        };
```

### References:

- [Data::Dumper](https://metacpan.org/pod/Data::Dumper)
- [perldoc perlref](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlref.html)
- [How can I print the contents of a hash in Perl?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1162245/2173773)

Answer (score 2):

It's always worth reading all of the documentation for the modules you're trying to use. The ["BUGS" section in the Data::Dumper manual](https://metacpan.org/pod/Data::Dumper#BUGS) says:

> Due to limitations of Perl subroutine call semantics, you cannot pass an array or hash. Prepend it with a `\` to pass its reference instead.